# How to send parameters from one http request to other in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to test a web application using JMeter.

I want to know how to transfer parameters from one http request to other, my web app has a login page and I have send my username and password, I am facing problem in this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Testing of login in jmeter, the proper way to pass the parameter via text or csv file, do the following steps as,

1.Create a text file (or csv file) containing the user names and passwords, separated by commas. Put this in the same directory as your test plan as,

[image]

2.Add a CSV DataSet configuration element to the test plan. Name the variables USER and PASS. also,Add a path to the filename in that element (I made sure to check the file path) as,

[image]

3.Replace the login name with ${USER} and the password with ${PASS} on the Log in (HTTP Request) Sampler as,
[image]

Hope this will help you,

Comment: I Have tried it and succeded in passing parameters.. but after logging into my account .. In view Tree Results , Response Data(HTML)... am getting the same login page

Comment: i think, you got logged out & complete the test.

Comment: What should I do .. logout or login and complete test ?

Comment: look at the my script, 1. home page, 2. login page 3. login inside page 4. then logout page. these pages execute sequentially just like normal process. so, follow this process. watch result in aggregate report

Answer (score 0):

If your website assumes login, you'll need to obtain some authentication details. Usually it's being handled by cookies. You need to look into [HTTP Cookie Manager](http://blazemeter.com/blog/using-http-cookie-manager-jmeter-not-cookie-jar) it'll allow to save cookies information across requests.