# simple Apache jmeter test

Tags: php, apache, session, jmeter, sugarcrm

I have a very simple test case. I want to login and logout of a php application (SugarCRM) multiple times. I have successfully carried out a couple of basic tests but I don't seem to get the hang of it. A short tutorial or a link to carry out the above will surely be sufficient. Thanks for reading.

Comment: hope this will help you, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421299/how-to-send-parameters-from-one-http-request-to-other-in-jmeter/19424166#19424166

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [ASP.NET Login Testing with JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blog/aspnet-login-testing-jmeter) guide will provide comprehensive information on how to properly perform your testing. It shouldn't be any difference for any other backend technology stack (Java, PHP, Ruby, etc.) as JMeter is acting on protocol level and doesn't care about underlying implementation software for application under test and correlation and cookie management is standard for all web applications.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do multiple times then try to use **CSV Data config** and import data from csv to login multiple times.

Create a CSV file with un & pwd for multiple users and try to run the script. Remember the number of threads you give should be equal to the no. of users, so that it will login multiple times