# jmeter session data and runtime parameter pass for multi user

Tags: session, attributes, runtime, jmeter, parameter-passing

I have scenario to test different concurrent  multiuser with different login and password from CSV ,
and passing session info & values and run time generated values pass as parameter to next screens for multiple pages. 
How can I build Test plan & configure JMeter.

Answer (score 0):

The below mentioned steps will help you achieve the above scenario:

1. Record the scenario
   http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf
2. Do correlation for dynamic parameters
   http://apache-jmeter.blogspot.com/2011/12/correlation-regular-expression.html
3. Use CSV for login credentials
   http://ivetetecedor.com/how-to-use-a-csv-file-with-jmeter/

hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

Go through the following link (my answer), [How to send parameters from one http request to other in jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19421299/how-to-send-parameters-from-one-http-request-to-other-in-jmeter/19424166#19424166)

make sure to add http cookie manager & http session manager in your test plan for run time generated values.